# How to optimize this for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

```
class MaximumDiffrence 
{ 
    
    int maxDiff(int arr[], int arr_size) 
    { 
        int max_diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
        int i, j; 
        for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) 
        { 
            for (j = i + 1; j < arr_size; j++) 
            { 
                if (arr[j] - arr[i] > max_diff) 
                    max_diff = arr[j] - arr[i]; 
            } 
        } 
        return max_diff; 
    } 

}
```

To find max difference is there any other way than using two for loops for a very large-sized list? Please help me optimize this. Thanks.

Comment: With one for loop, find the highest and lowest elements. The difference between those is the greatest difference.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and help me with the code? Thanks. @khelwood

Comment: Note that there is an issue in the way that this problem is posed.  If the largest number is very large and the smallest number is very negative, then the difference between them expressed as an `int` will be negative.  The result needs to be a `long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one for loop, you can find the highest and lowest elements. The difference between those is the greatest difference.

```java
class MaximumDifference { 

    int maxDiff(int arr[], int arr_size) {
        int lowest = arr[0];
        int highest = arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < arr_size; ++i) {
             int value = arr[i];
             if (value < lowest) {
                 lowest = value;
             }
             if (value > highest) {
                 highest = value;
             }
        }
        return highest - lowest;
    } 
}
```

Pitfalls:

- If `arr.length` us zero, or if `arr.length` is less than `arr_size`, this will error. I don't know what you'd want to return in those cases.
- If the difference between the highest and lowest element is big enough (e.g. if the highest is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and the lowest is negative), this could overflow, and a negative number would be returned. This can be mitigated by changing the return type to `long`, as suggested by Stephen C in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! It worked.